# Merging Two dataframes with differents length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, merge

I have two data sets df1 and df2 with differents length.

- df1 have request_id with general information,
- df2 have request_id (same value as df1) plus individual_id : Meaning same 'request_id' as multiple individual

Example : df1 has a shape of 238191 rows

| request_id | animal_presence | answer_creation_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 130667d2964de43c511d0ead7ac66b33- | f | 2019-02-11 22:3000 |
| b1cd62fcf24eebb0f685d5eaf55317a8- | f | 2019-02-12 09:0000 |
| 12cc0a18890bd4959fe42df3ae58838e- | f | 2019-02-01 21:00:00 |
| ae2d5b4dc181d29e430132f145da1556- | f | 2019-02-25 15:12:05.037 |
| d13a17ce36c832514fda2464e11c4a9f- | f | 2019-02-20 09:59:20.603 |

Example : df2 has a shape of 384133 rows

| request_id | individual_id | housing_situation_2_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 130667d2964de43c511d0ead7ac66b33 | b24a8cfaaf3663bac45ca3bcd24f0b36 | 20 |
| b1cd62fcf24eebb0f685d5eaf55317a8 | eef783d1bda82661a751c12c34aff8c2 | 20 |
| 12cc0a18890bd4959fe42df3ae58838e | 927b6fa58d6be263c411332835b11fec | 20 |
| ae2d5b4dc181d29e430132f145da1556 | 94181d5cf4a56cc84d12677df84e2e03 | 20 |
| d13a17ce36c832514fda2464e11c4a9f | e79d2e3f9ace50049f1796c098008c13 | 35 |

Problem with merging :

I tried to merge df1 and df2 as follow :

- df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='request_id')
- df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on='request_id')

But each time I obtain 384133 rows instead of 238191.

Note : I knews I would loss individual information, but I'm stuck :

- I don't know to merge both dataset AND explore the merge one per request_id (i.e. same group)
- How can I merge both dataset which allow me to explore the resulting DF by request_id, please ?

Thanks a lot !

Edit : @G. Anderson it was a copy/paste error : I forgot to remove index value in df2 example. Apologize.
I verified:

- df2['request_id'].nunique() is 238191,
  and
- df1 and df2['request_id'].nunique() are equal

Comment: In the sample you've provided, the requestIDs have completely different leading and trailing characters (`130667d2964de43c511d0ead7ac66b33-` vs `0 130667d2964de43c511d0ead7ac66b33`). What would be your expected output from merging your sample dataframes?

Comment: It is expected if duplicated `request_id` in one or both `DataFrames`. You can check it not by `df2['request_id'].nunique()` but by `df2[df2['request_id'].duplicated(keep=False)]` and similar for `df1`. This duplicates create combinations - so first duplicates is joined by all duplicates in second df, sedond dupe is join by all duplicates in second df... so if there are 5 same id in one df and 5 same id in second df is created new 25 rows.

Comment: Possible solution is remove duplicates, like `df2 = df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['request_id'])` and same for `df1` if necessary.